# Polars slow computation

Tags: python, python-polars

My polars snippet is running slower than similar snippet returning in pandas which should not be the case. What could be the potential issues?

The flow is relatively straight forward, first doing filtering, then aggregating and reindex.

```
df_data = pl.DataFrame({
    'category': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
    'dates': [
        date(2023, 7, 6),
        date(2023, 7, 6),
        date(2023, 7, 6),
        date(2023, 7, 7),
        date(2023, 7, 7),
        date(2023, 7, 8),
        date(2023, 7, 8)
    ],
    'costprice': [100, 200, 150, 250, 300, 120, 220],
    'fake': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'flag': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'sellprice': [80, 180, 130, 230, 280, 100, 200]
})

start_date = date(2023, 7, 6)
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=7)

past_dates = (
    pl.col('dates').is_between(start_date, end_date, closed='left')
)

filter_price = pl.all(
    pl.col('costprice') > 0,
    pl.col('fake') == 0,
    pl.col('flag') == 1
)

filter_sell_price = pl.all(
    pl.col('sellprice') > 0,
    pl.col('fake') == 0,
    pl.col('flag') == 1
)

groups = (
    df_data.filter(past_dates)
    .groupby('category', 'dates')
    .agg(
        q25=pl.col('costprice').filter(filter_price).quantile(0.25),
        q90=pl.col('costprice').filter(filter_price).quantile(0.9),
        q50_sell=pl.col('sellprice').filter(filter_sell_price).quantile(0.5)
    )
)

category = groups['category'].unique().to_list()
all_dates = pl.DataFrame({'dates': [start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]})
pl_index = all_dates.join(
              groups.select(pl.col('category').unique()), how='cross')

df_final = groups.join(pl_index, on=['dates','category'], how='outer').sort(['category','dates'])

df_info = df_final.groupby('category').agg(pl.count().alias('Count'))

groups = df_final.with_columns(pl.col('dates').dt.to_string('%Y-%m-%d')).groupby("category").all().join(df_info, on="category", how="left").to_dict(as_series=False)
```

Comment: How long is it taking? How long is the pandas version taking?

Comment: snippet shown here is small as I was not able to attach entire dataset, polars is taking about 1.5X times pandas for large dataset.

Comment: how many dates are in your original dataset?

Comment: in the first `groups = `, why do you do the three filters separately? can't you do them all together before doing `groupby`? Also, you can use `pl.date_range` to construct `all_dates `. Finally, do you know which part of your code is taking the longest?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity: No need to separate filter, how can I do in single filter?

Comment: `df_data.filter(past_dates & filter_price & filter_sell_price)`. I think it should produce the same result

Comment: Polars benefits greatly from utilizing it's optimizer. By using the LazyFrame api whenever possible, you will likely get much better performance as polars has more of an opportunity to optimize the queries.

Comment: How would lazyframe help in this case? I see the snippet having quite a few conditions and so lazyframe may not help much?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your filter definitions from

```
filter_sell_price = pl.all(
    pl.col('sellprice') > 0,
    pl.col('fake') == 0,
    pl.col('flag') == 1
)
```

to

```
filter_sell_price = (pl.col('sellprice') > 0) & (pl.col('fake') == 0
    ) & (pl.col('flag') == 1)
```

for all of them. I just copy and pasted the one example.

I've seen where using `pl.all` to gather filters takes noticeably longer than using `&`.